# Rails 4: Error messages not displaying with Bootstrap classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my application.html.erb file, I have:

```
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do | type, message | %>
  <div class="alert <%= flash_class(type) %>">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <%= message %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

I have the flash_class as a helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_class(type)
    case type
    when :alert
     "alert-error"
    when :notice
     "alert-success"
    else
     ""
    end
  end
end
```

Though what happens is the class isn't being appended in the HTML. When I create an error, the 'alert-error' class isn't added on:

[image]

Any ideas why that might be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be sending in `String` for type instead of `Symbol` in the `flash_class` method.

An easy fix would be calling `type.to_sym` in the `flash_class` helper method.

Comment: Thanks Vineeth, this was exactly what I was doing!

Comment: @iamryandrake, If and when Ruby comes up with static type checking, all these problems will go away.